# Childhood, English(England) rhymes are so disappointing,why?

Tags: early-modern-english, rhymes

When I was a kid, I was taught these poems:

`Georgie porgie`

`Humpty Dumpty` I know Humpty Dumpty was actually a canon, but still it was taught as Egg twins. So only take it on context of rhyme.

`Piggy on the railway`

and so many others .

All these poems have sad ending, sometimes they are also rude.

What was going on at that time, why these poems are like this?

Comment: The German childhood story tradition is even more gruesome.  I suspect that cautionary tales are meant to be jarring to modify behavior!  (I'm not sure this question is on-topic for this site though...)

Comment: Such poems, rhymes should've removed from kids curriculam long back. but they are still there and so I want to know what could be the reason. And originally why these written that way. When someone posts a question on stack it means after googling for hours and when no option left guy has come here. so please don't be party pooper!

Comment: You have no idea how many post questions on "What does X mean?" and "Is this correct?" when all that is required is a simple online search. So try to be a little more understanding and less on the defensive. Although Kristina didn't say you hadn't researched. BTW which websites did you look? What search items did you use? Any extra info will save users  time and unnecessary effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cultural history that is not specific to the English language.

Comment: But it's an interesting question, @choster! Give it a few hours at least.

Comment: It says `English Language & Usage
Q&A for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts` I dont know how come it is off topic?

Comment: It requires to dig out history pages, but not `cultural` but from `history of english language`, its origin.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Not for nothing are they called "Grimm's."

Comment: You're asking for "Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature" which is off-topic per the criteria in the Help Center: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  I do think it is an interesting question though!

Comment: [Halliwells's Nursery Rhymes of England (1886)](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/32415/32415-h/32415-h.htm) contains full text and illus. Most of them are centuries old and have been passed down via oral tradition. I remember my grandmother teaching me many of these rhymes and poems as an infant.  A favourite lullaby of mine was, '*Hush-a-bye, baby, on the tree top. When the wind blows, the cradle will rock. When the bough bends, the cradle will fall, down will come baby, bough, cradle and all.*' I don't think I worried too much about the baby....

Comment: Many of the rhymes are of at least Tudor origin, some being based on lines from Shakespeare's plays. It was a very different world to the 21st Century. Infant mortality was very high, adults died young, and facts like this would not have been hidden from children. Nursery rhymes were ways of preparing small children for the harsh facts of life, through make-believe, games, riddles and song.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Unfortunately, this site's criteria for a question to be on-topic include more than just "must be interesting."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase Isaac Asimov: "Science fiction isn't violent: read those old folk tales about parents abandoning their children in the woods and the happy ending is that they can live with their father again because their mother died! Hooray! Hooray!" (on Hansel and Gretel).

These folk tales / children's rhymes had lots of repetitions in them to be easily remembered and **were told to teach kids things**, not to entertain... E.G. the original Santa Claus had 2 black helpers who would take you away from your parents if you were bad *or* leave you presents when you were nice...

Comment: He still does! It's what the children sing here every year. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinterklaas

Comment: @Cerberus: Yeah, but he has more then 2 helpers nowadays and they're not called [Huginn and Muninn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huginn_and_Muninn) any more, because that's what this is based upon: [Odin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin), which makes the current controversy in The Netherlands so much funnier for those who do know about the history: his helpers were not black people, but black ravens crawling through the chimney. Over the last 2000 years, they lost more and more of their plumage, but kept the black soot... (Read up on the history of the Christmas tree too: pagan origins)

Comment: Still I think there it's too much violence for 2-3 year old kid.

Comment: I agree: I had nightmares for a week about the witch from Disney's Snow White back when I was a wee lad. Favour returned, question upvoted. @paul

Comment: It needs to be noted that many "Mother Goose" rhymes (Little Jack Horner, in particular) have been claimed to be essentially political editorials, never intended for children.

Comment: @HotLicks As I'm not a native English speaker (English is just my 3rd or 4th language, depending on how you count), I cannot edit that into my answer, but feel free to do so...